# Switch key and value in a dictionary of sets

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary something like:

```
d1 = {'0': {'a'}, '1': {'b'}, '2': {'c', 'd'}, '3': {'E','F','G'}}
```

and I want result like this

```
d2 = {'a': '0', 'b': '1', 'c': '2', 'd': '2', 'E': '3', 'F': '3', 'G': '3'}
```

so I tried

```
d2 = dict ((v, k) for k, v in d1.items())
```

but value is surrounded by set{}, so it didn't work well... 
is there any way that I can fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{v:k for k,vals in d1.items() for v in vals}
# {'a': '0', 'b': '1', 'c': '2', 'd': '2', 'E': '3', 'F': '3', 'G': '3'}
```

Note that you need an extra level of iteration over the values in each key here to get a flat dictionary.

Comment: I was curious and benchmarked, `{v:k for k in d1 for v in d1[k]}` was about 5-6% faster.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Could you please post your benchmark as an answer? It's hard to believe that but at the same time is interesting, thx

Comment: Curious. On a large one? @heap

Comment: @yatu No, on the given one.

Comment: @BPL Done (looks a little less now, I cleaned up the benchmark and ran it again).

Comment: @yatu Added a large one now, and your was faster there.

Answer (score 3):

Another dict comprehension:

```
>>> {v: k for k in d1 for v in d1[k]}
{'a': '0', 'b': '1', 'c': '2', 'd': '2', 'E': '3', 'F': '3', 'G': '3'}
```

Benchmark comparison with yatu's:

```
from timeit import repeat
setup = "d1 = {'0': {'a'}, '1': {'b'}, '2': {'c', 'd'}, '3': {'E','F','G'}}"
yatu = "{v:k for k,vals in d1.items() for v in vals}"
heap = "{v:k for k in d1 for v in d1[k]}"
for _ in range(3):
    print('yatu', min(repeat(yatu, setup)))
    print('heap', min(repeat(heap, setup)))
    print()
```

Results:

```
yatu 1.4274586000000227
heap 1.4059823000000051

yatu 1.4562267999999676
heap 1.3701727999999775

yatu 1.4313863999999512
heap 1.3878657000000203
```

Another benchmark, with a million keys/values:

```
setup = "d1 = {k: {k+1, k+2} for k in range(0, 10**6, 3)}"
for _ in range(3):
    print('yatu', min(repeat(yatu, setup, number=10)))
    print('heap', min(repeat(heap, setup, number=10)))
    print()

yatu 1.071519999999964
heap 1.1391495000000305

yatu 1.0880677000000105
heap 1.1534022000000732

yatu 1.0944767999999385
heap 1.1526202000000012
```

Comment: Really interesting, thanks for posting, it'd be interesting to know how much the difference increases when the values are larger... That said, +1 ;)

Comment: @BPL Added a large one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible solution to the given problem:

```
def flatten_dictionary(dct):
    d = {}
    for k, st_values in dct.items():
        for v in st_values:
            d[v] = k

    return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d1 = {'0': {'a'}, '1': {'b'}, '2': {'c', 'd'}, '3': {'E', 'F', 'G'}}
    d2 = flatten_dictionary(d1)
    print(d2)
```

Comment: I had confusion with how does v:k working on the loop on the another answer this one is more understandable for me ty.

Comment: @goldenasian Yeah, I know, that's why i decided to post a simpler version than yatu's one... no worries, once you've got more experience with python you'll get more comfortable with comprehension lists because, in fact, yatu's answer is more idiomatic than this one.